# Linq To nHibernate Method Not Found

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

**Code:**

```
public IEnumerable<CalendarItem> GetCalendarItems(DateTime? startDate = new DateTime?(), DateTime? endDate = new DateTime?())
    {
        if (startDate.HasValue && endDate.HasValue)
        { 
            var items = session.Linq<CalendarItem>()
                .Where(x => x.EventDate >= startDate.Value && x.EventDate <= endDate)
                .ToList<CalendarItem>(); //Error Here

            return items; 
        }


        //var items = session.QueryOver().OrderBy(x => x.EventDate);
        return session.CreateCriteria<CalendarItem>().List<CalendarItem>().OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate);

    }
```

**Exception**

```
 Method not found: 'System.Collections.IDictionary NHibernate.ISessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata()'.
```

Reference problem? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
I tried using a non-nullable date time and that gave the same error. Something is trying to call :

```
System.Collections.IDictionary NHibernate.ISessionFactory.GetAllClassMetadata()
```

When I check out  `ISessionFactory` via vs2010 the medadata does not show the"GetAllClassMetadata()" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ripping out my references for fluent/nhibernate. I used nuget to get the fluent package, but there may have been an issue with it. I downloaded the latest assemblies for fluent nhibernate and removed any reference to those asseblies I could find. This seems to have fixed the issue.

BTW...I am now using Query() rather than Linq()

Answer (score 1):

Probably linq provider doesn't understand startDate.Value getter call. try

```
.Where(x => x.EventDate >= startDate && x.EventDate <= endDate)
```

UPDATE

---

BTW, which version of nhibernate are you using? As far as I remember, .Linq is deprecated, use .Query instead

Comment: thanks, I tried changing to non-nullable DateTime and get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The NHibernate Linq provider is sometimes a bit buggy. Try to store the method parameters into local variables before using them in the Linq query.

```
public IEnumerable<CalendarItem> GetCalendarItems(DateTime? startDate = new DateTime?(), DateTime? endDate = new DateTime?())
{
    if (startDate.HasValue && endDate.HasValue)
    { 
      DateTime? start = startDate.Value;
      DateTime? end = endDate.Value;

      var items = session.Linq<CalendarItem>()
                         .Where(x => x.EventDate >= start && x.EventDate <= end)
                         .ToList<CalendarItem>();

      return items; 
    }
    ...
}
```